# How to initialize variable for FindBy annotation in Selenium with Kotlin?

Tags: selenium, kotlin, appium, findby, kotlin-lateinit

What is the best way to initialize a variable with the Selenium's `FindBy` annotation in Kotlin?

Something like

```
@FindBy(id = "example")
private lateinit var button: WebElement
```

or

```
@FindBy(id = "example")
private val button: WebElement? = null
```

or

```
@FindBy(id = "example")
private var button: WebElement? = null
```

or something else?

Note that all the previous methods works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You want late init because if the annotation fails to find it you will have a more understandable exception rather than null pointer exception

Answer (score -1):

The second option likely will not work, because the `val` is already initialized to `null` and cannot be changed.

I believe using the `lateinit` is the way to go in this case. It's meant for this purpose mainly.

Comment: It works, I tested it: when using the annotation `FindBy` it simply doesn't matter. Anyway, if you prefer, you can consider the same question but with `var` instead of `val` (I just added it in the main question).